# Can I use Extension Methods to implement an Interface?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like a class to implement an interface, I do not want to change the original class (that would add undesired dependecies).

I know I could inherit from the class and make it's child implement these methods, but then I am faced with a problem how to convert the parent class (that come from the data / ORM) to this presentation class.

If I implement all the interface required methods, will it count as being that interface or not ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it still won't count as implementing the interface.

Extension methods are nothing more than a way of calling static methods in a different kind of way. They don't affect object identity, inheritance etc at all.

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason why they couldn't? I.e. could extension methods be compiled into an object/interface's identity rather than just be syntactic sugar for static methods?

Comment: @GordonBean: Not without starting the feature again from scratch, no. The whole point is that they're just syntactic sugar. If you create an interface, I can add an extension method for it without you even being aware of it. That's really powerful.

Comment: Thank you. A number of times now I've found myself wanting to extend an existing class or interface so it will implement another interface (for example, making all implementers of an interface IComparable through use of only the interface methods). I.e. you make the interface, and I extend that interface type. Is this a feature that makes sense to implement, or am I thinking about the problem in the wrong way?

Comment: @GordonBean: That's fine, but that's completely different from extension methods. For example, consider `IEnumerable<T>` and the LINQ extension methods - they work without anyone having to implement any subclasses or sub-interfaces... they only need the members on `IEnumerable<T>`, and will work with any implementation.